# cannot execute POST method in android in

Tags: android, http-post

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static int flag;
    public boolean t;
    TextView view;
    Button button;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textvi);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
            String stringUrl="http://mohdgadi.netai.net/Register.php";
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
        }

    }
    private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            view.setText(result);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        String username="mohammed";
        String password="pass";
        int age=3;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Starts the query

            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age + ""));
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(dataToSend));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();



            conn.connect();
            String result="done";
           // is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
           // String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            //return contentAsString;
            return null;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }


    }
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

I try to Post data on my website but it deosnt seem to work when i press the button it doesnt update my website and database.
I commented out the inputstream code it worked completely fine in GET method but,post doesnt work and even my databse doesnt get updated.

This is my php file in public folder named Register.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com","a3039721_admin","123456ha","a3039721_databas");

    $data="";
    if(isset($age,$username,$password)){
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $data=$age.$username.$password;
    }
    echo $data;

    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users ( age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "iss", $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);*/
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked using `Postman`

Answer (score 0):

```
int response = conn.getResponseCode();
```

You  are trying to get the response code before you write your post data. Retrieve the response code after

```
conn.connect();
```

Comment: Yeah now unable to get url isnt showing but still data isnt getting posted on website
I also included my php file check it out

Answer (score 0):

**To make Post request you can use the following code :**

```
public void postRequest() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("<Enter url here>");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "StackOverFlow"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", "4th December"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

**For full tutorial and explanation click [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/)**